# Obtain Geometric Information and name from a map-design website

Tags: image, selenium, dictionary, web-scraping, location

There is a map-design website and this web-site's information was taken as snapshot by the 'web.archive.org'. Almost all information that I need can be read in this snapshot, though. The website is "https://web.archive.org/web/20130601211515/http://rasatlar.dsi.gov.tr/".

When the mouse comes upon a point image that has geometric location in itself, a title with code, and another information become visible inside the right-bottom box, and its X and Y location (Latitude, Longtitude) information can be seen at the right bottom corner. I need to gather these X, Y location and title, code information that this site reserves.

The script below tries to print a text in the box but I have this error, too.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
base_url = "https://www.katalon.com/"
verificationErrors = []
accept_next_alert = True  

driver.get("https://web.archive.org/web/20130601211515/http://rasatlar.dsi.gov.tr/")


a= driver.find_element_by_id("OpenLayers_Geometry_Point_6795")
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(a)
#driver.find_element_by_id("draggable").click()

b= driver.find_element_by_xpath((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='draggable']/p[1]")).text
print (b)
```

Error:

```
  WebDriverException: invalid argument: 'value' must be a string
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT (For Updated Question):**

Your xpath (below) is not working:

```
all_points = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@id,'OpenLayers_Geometry_Point_')]/img")))
```

Correct xpath is:

```
//div[contains(@id,'OpenLayers_Layer_Vector_RootContainer')]//*[contains(@id,'OpenLayers_Geometry_Point_')]
```

It looks like you are interested in getting information from box displayed in below image:

And Problem is that as soon as you move mouse away, information disappears. However, you can make it stay using "Break" feature available in CDT.

I have posted the HTML structure in below image (right side), which you can reference to get correct xpath:

[image]

**Xpath to get header element (i.e. E17A008/TARSUS IRMAĞI ):**

```
//*[@id="draggable"]/h1
```

**Xpath to get second element i.e. MUHAT KÖPRÜSÜ**

```
//*[@id="draggable"]/p[1]
```

Similarly, you should be able to get relevant xpath for other elements.

> How to use Break:

- Right click on Right Box (Don't worry, even if it's empty box).
- Click On Inspect -> Right click on element displayed in dev tool i.e. `<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content ui-draggable"></div>`
- Click on **Break On -> Subtree modification**

Now, if you try to select another address, this will break, whenever any modification occur on this element.

Comment: If I find the Id elements, I will do something with your comments but I am having timeout error with the script above.

Comment: Hey, Raj, can you help me for the further coding?

Comment: At which particular code statement, you are getting timeout error? Can you post what you tried and what's the exception in detail?

Comment: Ok, I am going to update asap, please keep in contact.

Comment: Hi Raj, I updated with the Error I am having. Could you look at that?

Comment: @fyec, Pleas check my updated answer. Xpath which you are using in code doesn't work. Check my answer and try with updated xpath. Always try to highlight xpath in chorme CDT to verify if it's correct.

Comment: Thank you, could you check new updated error, please?